# Complex layout in UIView that animates its content

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, layout, uiview

I'm having this general question about a problem that arises very often when I'm designing complex UIViews that require a special layout and animations at the same time.

What I'm currently building is the same kind of view that the Mail app uses on iOS to present a list of recipients when writing an email (the blue badges container) :

[image: the view]

So I understand and know how I would build such a view, but I always have this question when facing such a case : How do you handle the complex layout (layouting all the blue rounded rectangles) and their animations at the same time (when adding or removing a recipient) ?

**1. Normally I would reimplement :**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

to reflect the state of the view at the layout moment (ie layout each blue rounded UIButton side by side) according to my current bounds and just add and animate a UIButton when someone adds a new person to the list.

But what would happen to the animation if a layout pass is already running? (this may be a dumb question since everything is supposed to happen on the main thread and so no concurrency is involved here, but I'm not sure on how to handle this)

I think those two things (layout and animations) are not supposed to happen at the same time, since the main runloop "enqueues work and dequeues work" one "block" at a time (but maybe an animation is just hundreds of blocks enqueued that draw different things overtime, which could easily be compromised by a layout block in between??)

**2. Also, would this solution be acceptable ?**

- Reimplement layoutSubviews the exact same way to handle the correct layout of my subviews
- When someone adds or deletes a person, just call this to re-position everything animated

  ```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
      [self setNeedsLayout];
      [self layoutIfNeeded];
  }];
  ```

As you can see, lots of questions here, I don't know exactly how to handle this gracefully.

Both of these solutions have been tested and approved but the thing is which one is the best ?

Do you have a better solution ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you mean animations applied to a view for which `layoutSubviews` method is implemented, e.g. animated change of its frame. If something is changed in your view while animation is ongoing that causes the view to re-layout, then `layoutSubviews` method will be called.

Basically, such kind of animations is nothing more than following:

- change view's frame (actually, frame of a view's layer) by some small value (e.g. increase origin's Y coordinate by 1 pixel)
- call `layoutSubviews`, if needed
- redraw view (i.e. its layer)
- change view's frame by some small value
- call `layoutSubviews`, if needed
- redraw view
- **...**
- repeat steps above until view's properties reach target values

All those steps are performed on the main thread, so steps above are consecutive and are not concurrent.

Generally speaking, the `layoutSubviews` method should define coordinates and sizes of subviews basing on its own bounds. Animations change the view's frame and correspondingly its bounds, so your implementation of the `layoutSubviews` method is supposed to handle those changes correctly.

That is, the answer for your question is implement correctly `layoutSubviews` method.

**P.S.** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22557077/1310204) has a great explanation of how animations are implemented.

---

## Update

It seems that previously I understood the question incorrectly. My understanding was:

> What happens if `layoutSubviews` method is called for a view being animated?
>   That is, I assumed that there is some view which e.g. changes its `y` coordinate with animation, the `layoutSubviews` method is called for this view during animation, and some subview of the view changes its position in the `layoutSubviews`.

After clarification from @Nicolas, my understanding is as follows:

> Let's have some view (`'Parent'`) with a subview (`'Child'`); let's animate this subview (`'Child'`); let's call `layoutSubviews` method of the `'Parent'` view and change `'Child'` subview's frame in this `layoutSubviews` method while animation is ongoing. What will happen?

### Background Theory:

`UIView` itself doesn't render any content; it's done by Core Animation layers. Each view has an associated `CALayer` which holds a bitmap snapshot of a view. In fact, `UIView` is just a thin component above Core Animation Layer which performs actual drawing using view's bitmap snapshots. Such mechanism optimizes drawing: rasterized bitmap can be rendered quickly by graphics hardware; bitmap snapshots are unchanged if a view structure is not changed, that is they are 'cahced'.

Core Animation Layers hierarchy matches `UIView`'s hierarchy; that is, if some `UIView` has a subview, then a Core Animation layer corresponding to the container `UIView` has a sublayer corresponding to the subview.

Well... In fact, each `UIView` has even more than 1 corresponding `CALayer`. `UIView` hierarchy produces 3 matching Core Animation Layers trees:

- Layer Tree - these are layers we used to use through the `UIView`'s `layer` property
- Presentation Tree - layers containing the in-flight values for any running animations. Whereas the layer tree objects contain the target values for an animation, the objects in the presentation tree reflect the current values as they appear onscreen. You should never modify the objects in this tree. Instead, you use these objects to read current animation values, perhaps to create a new animation starting at those values.
- Objects in the render tree perform the actual animations and are private to Core Animation.

Change of UIView's properties such as frame is actually change of CALayer's property. That is, UIView's property is a wrapper around corresponding CALayer property.

Animation of UIView's frame is actually change of CALayer's frame; frame of the layer from Layer Tree is set to the target value immediately whereas change of frame value of layer from presentation tree is stretched in time. The following call:
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.label.frame;
            frame.origin.y = 527;
            self.label.frame = frame;
        }];
doesn't mean that `self.label`'s `drawRect:` method will be called multiple times during next 5 seconds; it means that `y`-coordinate of the presentation tree's `CALayer` corresponding to the `self.label` will change incrementally from initial to target value during these 5 seconds, and `self.label`'s bitmap snapshot stored in this `CALayer` will be redrawn multiple times according to changes of its `y`-coordinate.

### Answer:

Given this background, now we can answer the original question.

So, we have ongoing animation for a child view, and `layoutSubviews` method gets called for a parent view; in this method, child view's frame gets changed. It means that frame of a layer assiciated with the child view will be immediately set to the new value. At the same time, layer from the presentation tree has some intermidiate values (according to ongoing animation); setting new frame just changes target value for presentation tree layer, so that animation will continue to the new target.

That is, result of situation described in the original question is a 'jumping' animation. Please see demonstration in the [GitHub sample project](https://github.com/nikolay-mamaev/LayoutSubviewsTest).

### Solution for such complex cases

In your `layoutSubviews` method, if an animation is ongoing, you need to use in-flight animation coordinates. You can obtain them with the `presentationLayer` method of `CALayer` associated with a view. That is, if a view being animated is called `aView`, then presentation layer for this view can be accessed using `[aView.layer presentationLayer]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, I was more focused on animating the content (ie the subviews) of the view, not the view frame itself.
Also, what would happen to the animation (of the view or subviews) if a layout pass happens at the same time?

Comment: Also, what solution # would you use (or please explain your own :)) regarding this kind of animated layout?

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer. 3 questions arise: - Why would you use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` in `awakeFromNib` (for MyView in your GitHub project) ? - Is the current running animation cancelled for -frame when I set a new frame or, as you said, the existing animation is just "modified"? - Does setting a new Y (or X) to the label (ie. just changing its position) will redraw it every time or simply redraw it once, and use its backing cached bitmap? Same question with changing Width or Height? Will this redraw everything for each frame (Core Animation side)?

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, here are answers for your questions. (1) I used the dispatch_async() just to have the timer fired first time after the view is fully loaded and configured. (2) Animation lasts for time passed to the call of the UIView's animateWithDuration:animations: method (i.e. 5 seconds in my case). Animation is just step-by-step change of UIView's parameters (in my case - frame) from source to target values, so changing parameters being animated while animation is ongoing is a change of run-time intermediate values. That is, animation is 'modified'.

Comment: (3) I think that UIView uses cached bitmap as long as it's possible; that is, the UIView is not redrawn until change of some UIView's parameters affecting its contents. Change of view's x and y doesn't affect its content, so I believe the cached bitmap is used instead of redrawing (creating a new bitmap); but change of width/height changes view's contents, so I think bitmap is re-created in this case. I don't think CoreAnimation deals anyhow with redrawing of a view, it just uses view's bitmap during rendering the screen; rather it's UIView's responsibility to prepare this bitmap.

Comment: Once bitmap is prepared, it's used by CoreAnimation until there is need to re-create the bitmap (e.g. due to width change). Hope your original question is answered.